# return age in years and months from date of birth

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Using MySQL, I return the age in years and months as separate fields in a query.

This may well be a premature optimization but the duplicate calls to datediff and from_days in this query are upsetting.

Is it possible to get the **from_days(datediff(now(), user_birthdate))** factored into a single call without a nested query?

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    year(from_days(datediff(now(), user_birthdate))) as years,
    month(from_days(datediff(now(), user_birthdate))) as months
```

or... would a nested query be a win over this current query?

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    YEAR(age) AS years,
    MONTH(age) AS months
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *, FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(user_birthdate)) AS age
    FROM
        users) AS users_temp
```

If someone can give me some hints about the best way to test the relative performance of these two methods empirically, that would be useful too

Comment: Just populate a table with 10K rows and time both methods. I think that would be as empirical as you can get.

Comment: Nested queries are slower than repeated function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with variables, like this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  year(@fecha:=from_days(datediff(now(), user_birthdate))) as years,
  month(@fecha) as months
```

But have caution with the execution order. If you assign the value in SELECT don't expect same value in WHERE part.

Comment: Bah, can't use variables in a view, which is a drag, but thanks anyway